# Не могу обратиться в экземпляре класса к статическому свойству

Tags: javascript

Создаю класс со статическим свойством и простым методом, который возвращает пароль, составленный из имени и статического свойства. Затем создаю экземпляр класса и в вызове метода получаю 'Annundefined'. В чем причина?

```
class User {
  constructor(name, surname) {
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
  }

  static pass = '12345';

  getPassword() {
    return ‘${this.name}${this.pass}’;
  }
}

let user1 = new User('Ann', 'Smith');
console.log(user1.getPassword());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том, что к статическим свойствам внутри класса надо обращаться по имени самого класса, а не через this. Так как в экземпляре просто нет свойства pass.

```
class User {
  constructor(name, surname) {
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
  }

  static pass = '12345';

  getPassword() {
    return ‘${this.name}${User.pass}’;  // нужно обращаться по имени класса к статическому свойству
  }
}

let user1 = new User('Ann', 'Smith');
console.log(user1.getPassword());
```